# All users distinct

Tags: php, mongodb-query, distinct

I'm trying a simple query to have all users in distinct mode.

```
<?php
//all users distinct
 $un = $collection->distinct("creato_da");
 foreach ($un as $u) {
  echo $u["creato_da"] . " - ";
 }
?>
```

my result is:

> **m - m - a**

Instead I expected:

> **mery - marlene - albert**

where I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `foreach` is returning a list of distinct strings.  When you use `$u["creato_da"]` this is accessing characters of a string and it will be treated as `$u[0]` which will fetch the first character of the string.  Instead you need...

```
echo $u . " - ";
```

Comment: great works, thanks.

Now I would like to try to sort the result like this:

albert - marlene - mery 

and I tried this query 

`$un = $collection->distinct("creato_da").sort({'creato_da': 1});`

but it does not work...